# How to get access to database that was created in some other class?

Tags: android, database

I've been reading a lot of posts on Stackoverflow about that question. Almost all the answers were about using `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and this is exactly what I'm doing.

My issue is I have a database that stores some statistics and I want to output the statistics in `StatsActivity`. The problem is I create a database for statistics in `MainActivity` and I don't know how to access it in `StatsActivity`.

I was trying to instantiate an instance of `StatsDB` in `StatsActivity` as it has been told in other threads. StatsDB is a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and represents database for statistics.

**StatsActivity.java**

```
public class StatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stats);

        StatsDB stats = new StatsDB(this);
        Cursor curs = stats.getAllStats();

        TextView created = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_Created_Counter);
        TextView participated = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_Participated_Counter);
    }
}
```

However, I keep receiving Runtime error with following traceback from the string `Cursor curs = stats.getAllStats();`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kirill.myapplication/com.example.kirill.myapplication.StatsActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: StatsDatabase (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, type, number FROM StatsDatabase
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2696)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2757)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: StatsDatabase (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, type, number FROM StatsDatabase
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1204)
                  at com.example.kirill.myapplication.StatsDB.getAllStats(StatsDB.java:65)
                  at com.example.kirill.myapplication.StatsActivity.onCreate(StatsActivity.java:23)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6847)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2649)
```

It says that there is no database with name `StatsDatabase`, but I'm instanstiating it `MainActivity`:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.mapButton:
                Intent intentMap = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentMap);
                break;
            case R.id.settingsButton:
                Intent intentSettings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSettings);
                break;
            case R.id.statsButton:
                Intent intentStats = new Intent(this, StatsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentStats);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Button mapBtn;
    Button statsBtn;
    Button settingsBtn;

    StatsDB stats;
    LocationsDB locations;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stats = new StatsDB(this);
        locations = new LocationsDB(this);

        mapBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
        statsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.statsButton);
        settingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);

        mapBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        statsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

**StatsDB.java**

```
package com.example.kirill.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by kirill on 21.11.17.
 */

public class StatsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DATABASE_STATS = "StatsDatabase";

    private static int VERSION = 1;

    public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";

    public static final String FIELD_TYPE = "type";

    public static final String FIELD_NUMBER = "number";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "stats";

    private SQLiteDatabase statsDB;

    public StatsDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_STATS, null, VERSION);
        statsDB = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues created = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues participated = new ContentValues();
        created.put(FIELD_TYPE, "Created");
        created.put(FIELD_NUMBER, "0");
        participated.put(FIELD_TYPE, "Participated");
        participated.put(FIELD_NUMBER, "0");

        statsDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, created);
        statsDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, participated);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                FIELD_TYPE + " string , " +
                FIELD_NUMBER + " int " +
                " ) ";

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public long insert(ContentValues contentValues){
        long rowID = statsDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        return rowID;
    }

    public int del(){
        int cnt = statsDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null , null);
        return cnt;
    }

    public Cursor getAllStats(){
        return statsDB.query(DATABASE_STATS, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_TYPE , FIELD_NUMBER} , null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }


}
```

**LocationsDB.java**

```
package com.example.kirill.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by kirill on 21.11.17.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class LocationsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /** Database name */
    private static String DATABASE_LOCATIONS = "locationmarkersqlite";

    /** Version number of the database */
    private static int VERSION = 1;

    /** Field 1 of the table locations, which is the primary key */
    public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";

    /** Field 2 of the table locations, stores the latitude */
    public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";

    /** Field 3 of the table locations, stores the longitude*/
    public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";

    /** Field 4 of the table locations, stores the zoom level of map*/
    public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zom";

    /** A constant, stores the the table name */
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";

    /** An instance variable for SQLiteDatabase */
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    /** Constructor */
    public LocationsDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_LOCATIONS, null, VERSION);
        this.mDB = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /** This is a callback method, invoked when the method getReadableDatabase() / getWritableDatabase() is called
     * provided the database does not exists
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
                FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
                FIELD_ZOOM + " text " +
                " ) ";

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    /** Inserts a new location to the table locations */
    public long insert(ContentValues contentValues){
        long rowID = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        return rowID;
    }

    /** Deletes all locations from the table */
    public int del(){
        int cnt = mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null , null);
        return cnt;
    }



    /** Returns all the locations from the table */
    public Cursor getAllLocations(){
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_LAT , FIELD_LNG, FIELD_ZOOM } , null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

}
```

So what am I doing wrong in this approach or are there any others?

Comment: Post your `StatsDB` and `LocationsDB` code

Comment: @ShylendraMadda Added.

Comment: I think you didn't commit .. after create table

Comment: @RakChunJang Can you clarify what you mean, since I'm a newbie?

Comment: @Rak Not the problem. You can't select from a database... Typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`statsDB.query(DATABASE_STATS`... You need to use the table there, not the database

Your error is telling you `no such table: StatsDatabase`, which is true. The table you created is named `stats`